# A simple connected $(2k + 1)$-regular graph, which is $2k$-edge connected (k ≥ 1), has a perfect matching.

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that a simple connected $(2k + 1)$-regular graph, which is
$2k$-edge connected (k ≥ 1), has a perfect matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is generalized by Bäbler's theorem. You can read it with proof [here](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%208.PDF) (theorem 8.11).